# Visual composer Masonry grid doesn't load

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I'm using [insert_php] plugin in Wordpress and I have inserted php function in it.If I set the block with the function before the the masonry grid it doesn't load.
If I move the block with the function after the grid it works well.
In console log is appearing an alert:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: {'status':'Nothing found'}

How can I sole that?
Grid before php block

[image]

Block php before the grid

[image]

Comment: you should paste your code here as text

Comment: i have inserted a function in functions.php
and i call it in the page content

Comment: is too long the function

Comment: [link](https://shrib.com/li0w2CpLMB7jB5D)

Comment: in the link are the php functions that i used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create a page template. This page template can be used to create PHP for your page to load, and you can even use 
    `<?php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode]'); ?>`

To create a template just copy your page.php into a new file called tpl_test.php.
Then make sure to have this in the very first line:

```
`<?php
/* 
    Template Name: Test Template
*/
?>`
```

Then, a small window will show up on the back-end of WordPress when you edit the page. In the right hand column you need to select the page template for the page you just created, and update the page. then, any code you put in the custom Page Template will display correctly on your WordPress site. Also, make sure `<?php the_content() ?>` is below your grid you are trying to output.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page in question?

Comment: Try using a '<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>' between them? I'm not sure why it wouldn't even render in a page template. It looks like the div for the grid is there, but no content is loading. Last resort could be having those two shortcodes on two different pages.